# How to sum value in the existing array object based on condition in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

I have two array list `list1` and `list2`, property `name` matches, then sum all the `qty` of list1 and list2 matched object, return updated qty of list1

```
function resultantArray(list1, list2){
  let sum = list2.map(o => o.qty|| 0).reduce((a, c) => { return a + c });
   list1.forEach(item=>{      
    list2.find(elm => elm.productcode == item.productcode).qty= sum;
   });
}

var list1 = [
  {id:1, name: "IN",qty: 1},
  {id:2, name: "TH"},
  {id:3, name: "AU"}
]
var list2 = [
  {id:3, name: "IN", qty:1},
  {id:5, name: "IN", qty:1},
  {id:4, name: "TH", qty: 2},
  {id:1, name: "SG", qty: 3}
]
```

Expected Output:

```
 [
  {id:1, name: "IN",qty: 3},
  {id:2, name: "TH", qty: 2},
  {id:3, name: "AU"}
]
```

Comment: shouldn't `TH` be qty `2` in output object?... What happens to items missing by name in list 2?

Comment: @briosheje thanks fore reply, i have updated the ouptut, `TH` should be included, in `list2` missing by name also should be included,

Comment: What should happen if in `list2` the entry for `TH` has no `qty`? What does it mean when there is no `qty` property? Is it equivalent with `qty: 0`?

Comment: @trincot thanks for rply, yes its equivalent to `qty: 0`

Comment: just a tip, consider including your question on the body of the question, not just on the title. It really makes it more clear what you are looking for.

Comment: @jpnadas okay thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could create a Map to create the result list, but keyed by name.
Then iterate the second list and update the objects in the map accordingly.
Finally extract the values into the result list.

The use of the Map avoids that you have use `find` or `filter` or some other nested loop, and makes the algorithm run in linear time.

```js
var list1 = [{id:1, name: "IN", qty: 1},{id:2, name: "TH"},{id:3, name: "AU"}]
var list2 = [{id:3, name: "IN", qty:1},{id:5, name: "IN", qty:1},{id:4, name: "TH", qty: 2},{id:1, name: "SG", qty: 3}];

const map = new Map(list1.map(o => [o.name, {...o}]));
for (let o of list2) {
    let p = map.get(o.name);
    if (p && o.qty) p.qty = (p.qty || 0) + o.qty;
}
const result = Array.from(map.values());

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var list1 = [
  {id:1, name: "IN",qty: 1},
  {id:2, name: "TH"},
  {id:3, name: "AU"}
]
var list2 = [
  {id:3, name: "IN", qty:1},
  {id:5, name: "IN", qty:1},
  {id:4, name: "TH", qty: 2},
  {id:1, name: "SG", qty: 3}
]

function process(l1, l2) {
   let qtys = {};
   l1.concat(l2).forEach(o => {
      let q = o.qty || 0;
      if (qtys[o.name] === undefined) {
        qtys[o.name] = o.qty;  // track its qty
      } else {
        qtys[o.name] += o.qty; // add its qty
      }     
   });
   let id = 1;
   return l1.map(o => {
      let r = {id: id++, name: o.name};
      if (qtys[o.name]) r.qty = qtys[o.name];
      return r;
   });
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(process(list1, list2)));
```

This seems to solve the problem. The first `forEach` loop adds up all quantities. The second loop constructs the result, looking up only entries in `list1`. Note that this only works as expected if there are no duplicates in `list1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make use of `map` function, logic would be to filter the item from second list and get length and add one for being the current element, afterwards if the `qty` is more than one then record accordingly. Here is the working example:

```js
var list1 = [
  {id:1, name: "IN",qty: 1},
  {id:2, name: "TH"},
  {id:3, name: "AU"}
]
var list2 = [
  {id:3, name: "IN", qty:1},
  {id:5, name: "IN", qty:1},
  {id:4, name: "TH", qty: 2},
  {id:1, name: "SG", qty: 3}
]

var result = list1.map(item=>{
   qty = list2.filter(k=>k.name==item.name).length+1;
   return qty>1 ? {...item, qty} : item;
});

console.log(result);
```